# Почему git дублирует изменения, которые были рассинхронизированы?

Tags: git, gitlab

1. В удаленный репозиторий вносятся изменения "А"
2. В локальный репозиторий тоже вносятся изменения (в другой файл) "Б"
3. При попытки закоммитить и запушить гит ругается, что нужно сделать пулл
4. Делаю пулл и пуш

В итоге, вижу в удаленном репозитории в истории коммитов

- "А"
- "Б"
- коммит Merge branch 'main' of gitlab.com:username/repo, который в точности повторяет коммит "А", - не пойму, почему он возникает, ведь по логике эти изменения уже есть в удаленном репозитории?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ¿А что вы видите у себя локально выполнив `git log --all --graph` между шагами 3 и 4? ¿У вас случаем не настроен автомердж при пулл?

Comment: добавил картинку. Видимо автомерд настроен. Примерно понял, т.е. как будто бы создается новая ветка с изменениями а потом она же вливается в мастер.

Comment: Единственное что странно когда я вношу изменения в веб интерфейсе гитлаба напрямую в удаленный репозиторий то он выделил как бы эти измения в "отдельную ветку", а мои изменения локальные как бы продолжают основную ветку. И потом именно удаленные изменения вливаются в мою ветку опять же.  Т.е. я два раза вижу изменения которые сделаны напрямую в удаленном репозитории. Хотя так чисто по логике там то они как раз уже и были...

Comment: чтобы такого не происходило надо делать git pull --rebase

Comment: Действие для pull по-умолчанию можно перенастроить. А еще лучше делать `git fetch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это особенности вашего инструмента для просмотра истории.

Обозначим начальное состояние файла A как A0, а конечное - как A1. Аналогично поступим  и с файлом B.

Теперь посмотрим как выглядит граф коммитов после слияния (старые коммиты снизу):

```
     (A1, B1)
      /    \
(A1, B0)   (A0, B1)
      \    /
     (A0, B0)
```

При просмотре истории git сравнивает содержимое коммита с его родителем и показывает разницу.

Так, для коммита (A1, B0) он сравнивает его с (A0, B0) и видит различия в файле A. А для коммита (A0, B1) он аналогичным образом видит различия в файле B.

Но у коммита (A1, B1) не один родитель, а два, и что показывать для него?

Продвинутые инструменты, вроде Git Extensions, при просмотре этого коммита показывают следующее:

1. отличия от первого родителя: (A1, B1) - (A1, B0) = изменён файл B
2. отличия от второго родителя: (A1, B1) - (A0, B1) = изменён файл A
3. отличия от обоих родителей - не найдены

А вот глупые инструменты, вроде веб-интерфейсов github и gitlab, сравнивают только с первым родителем и на этом успокаиваются. Но при этом они не забывают показать в истории обе ветки, отчего у вас и создаётся впечатление дублирования изменений.